# Is it a good idea to create an index just for new data to increase index creation performance?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index-tuning, postgresql-9.5

I have a table with about **350 M** rows with **45 GB,** it has around **10** columns ,simplified version below

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
    ID NUMERIC(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    CREATION TIMESTAMP,
    VALUE DECIMAL(10, 2),
    USER_ID NUMERIC(20)
    ....
)
```

Once known that

- Table have a really high concurrency
- It receives about **3M** INSERTS and **5M** UPDATES per day, update uses the PK
- By company policies reasons

  - I must keep old data to grant history
  - I can't partitioning that table
  - I'm really going to have this one table with all data and there is not chance to change that
- I have to create an index for (`CREATION`, `USER_ID`) columns

**Is it a good idea to create an index excluding old data to get the index created faster, avoiding table locks and save storage knowing that my queries will just hit the new data?**

```
CREATE INDEX ON PAYMENT(CREATION, USER_ID) WHERE CREATION > TIMESTAMP '2018-03-25 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Check the execution plan

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Does explain works with create index statement? I tried it but I get an error

Comment: [This answer days it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032896/postgresql-probabilities-explain-on-create-index)

Comment: you need to check the execution plan of the **query** that is supposed to use the index.

Comment: I see, I think my question wasn't clear, I'm worried about the create index execution impact to production database, so using that where statement at create index will help to create the index faster with less locking or it will work just like a normal create index? We are pretending to execute that with the database online

Comment: The index will only make sense to begin with if all your queries include that condition on the `creation` column. If you are concerned about locking, create the index `concurrently`

Answer (score 0):

if you create a partial index then your queries will have also include the condition used to create the index. if they do not the index will be of no use.

when creating the index there will probably need to be a scan of the entire table your only win is a smaller index size.

What index will help queries most depends on what information you want from the table. are you sure that there are enough payments with the exact same creation that including userid as the second term in the index is justified? bear in mind that timestamp is 8 bytes while numeric(20) is 16 bytes, so an index on timestamp only will also be more compact.

An index on `payment (userid, creation)` will be more useful in the case where you want you find the most recent record, or the payment history, for any particular userid.

Comment: My point here is to create that index with the minimum of impact to the database, as fast as it can be and avoiding lock, so that's why I put where statement at create index statement, the index itself is fine.